Check50 not found Flask_login module
I have issue with flask_login not found when running CS50 problem set 9 Check50.
App itself running well, flask has to errors.
when trying to make Check50 receiving faults because it cant find and start app.
I have tried pip install flask-login, but error repeats. activation, requirements installation, nothing works...
if anyone have some suggestion, please welcome.
:) app.py exists
:| application starts up
check50 ran into an error while running checks!
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/check50/runner.py", line 148, in wrapper
state = check(*args)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/check50/cs50/problems/finance/__init__.py", line 22, in startup
Finance().get("/").status(200)
^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/check50/cs50/problems/finance/__init__.py", line 193, in __init__
super().__init__(self.APP_NAME)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/check50/flask.py", line 34, in __init__
mod = internal.import_file(path.stem, path.name)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/check50/internal.py", line 185, in import_file
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/tmp80jn3rf5/startup/app.py", line 8, in <module>
from flask_login import (

:| register page has all required elements
can't check until a frown turns upside down


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
